# Dynamic # of states using for loop and setState . Then need to use states after all have been set

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, setstate

Dynamic number of states. The number of states are dynamic and depends on this `mppt` number which depends on the user input. I create the states and then after they are all created in the for loop... I'd like to do something with it. I would normally do it in the callback, but I'm using a for loop to create the dynamic number of states. This sets up the defaults and number of elements depending on `mppt` number. Afterwards, it will be updated by an `onChange`.

```
const defaultValues = {
    1:{
        isc: 10.88,
power: 3834.5999999999995,
vmp: 497,
voc: 584.3312579999999,
se: 14,
st: 1,
    },


2: {isc: 9.00,
    power: 3834.5999999999995,
    vmp: 600,
    voc: 584.3312579999999,
    se: 12,
    st: 1},
}

const mppt = 2


.
.
.


   componentDidMount(){
        console.log('Sizing Mounted?')
        for(let i=1 ; i <= mppt ; i++){
            console.log(i)
            this.setState({ [`${i}`] : defaultValues[i]}, ()=>{
                console.log('state been set?')
                console.log(this.state[`${i}`]) //this works
            })
        }
        console.log('Check if state has been checked by here to feed into next function')
        console.log(this.state[`1`])  // undefined

        //This function uses the new set states 
        this.createElementDefaults()  //uses undefined state values

    }
```

The asyncronous nature of setStates is messing with this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building the object first, set it into the state and then use your funciton in the callback:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let s = {};
    for (let i = 1; i <= mppt; i++) {
      s[`${i}`] = defaultValues[i];
    }

    this.setState((prevState) => ({ ...s }), () => {
        console.log(this.state);
        this.createElementDefaults()
    });
  }
```

Comment: I'd be going from 1:{} , 2:{}  --> s : {1 :{}, 2:{}}  The state information will change but only on 1 or 2 or 'n' at any time.  Won't this require me to update the entire 's' object when updating 1, 2, ....n ?   I was trying to keep them separate.

Comment: Nevermind, that worked!!!   What is this {...s} called so I can research that?

Comment: It is called the spread operator in JS. You can also find it as object destructuring.